# Stress-energy tensor of perfect fluid: changing reference system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, fluid-dynamics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

The stress-energy tensor for a perfect fluid is given by,

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\rho_0c^2h\frac{u^\mu u^\nu}{c^2}+pg^{\mu\nu}$$

where $h=1+\epsilon+\frac{p}{c^2\rho_0}$, $\rho_0$ the rest energy density, $p$ the pressure, and $u$ the velocity.

Now if we are in a reference system moving with the perfect fluid, the energy-stress tensor takes the diagonal form,

$$T^\mu_\nu=\left (\begin{matrix} -\mu c^2 & 0 & 0& 0 \\ 0 & p & 0& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & p& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0& p \end{matrix}\right )$$

where $\mu c^2=\rho_0(1+\epsilon)c^2$. I have to demonstrate this and write explicitly the transformation, however I have really no idea on how to proceed especially since this tensor has mixed indices. Particularly, I don't understand how one can change the reference system to make the stress-energy tensor diagonal.

I have already shown that $\mu c^2=\rho_0(1+\epsilon)c^2$, and from a pure physical argument, I know that the matrix for the stress-tensor should be diagonal in the reference system moving with the perfect fluid since all momenta from the fluid particles should cancel each other out, so all the terms outside of the diagonal should average to zero. This is equivalent to writing $u^\mu=(c,0,0,0)$

I tried writting explicitly the original form of $T^{\mu\nu}$, assuming $g^{\mu\nu}=(-,+,+,+)$

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\left (\begin{matrix} \rho_0 h u^0u^0 -p & \rho_0 h u^1u^0 & \rho_0 h u^2u^0 & \rho_0 h u^3u^0 \\ \rho_0 h u^0u^1 & \rho_0 h u^1u^1 +p & \rho_0 h u^2u^1 & \rho_0 h u^3u^1 \\ \rho_0 h u^0u^2 & \rho_0 h u^1u^2 & \rho_0 h u^2u^2 +p & \rho_0 h u^3u^2 \\ \rho_0 h u^0u^3 & \rho_0 h u^1u^3 & \rho_0 h u^2u^3 & \rho_0 h u^3u^3 +p \end{matrix}\right )$$

Using $\mu c^2=\rho_0(1+\epsilon)c^2$ we can rewritte this as,

$$T^{\mu\nu}=\left (\begin{matrix} \mu u^0 u^0 +p(\frac{u^0 u^0}{c^2}-1) & \mu u^1 u^0 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^2 u^0 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^3 u^0 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) \\ \mu u^0 u^1 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^1 u^1 +p(\frac{u^1 u^1}{c^2}-1) & \mu u^2 u^1 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^3 u^1 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) \\ \mu u^0 u^2 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^1 u^2 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^2 u^2 +p(\frac{u^2 u^2}{c^2}-1) & \mu u^3 u^2 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) \\ \mu u^0 u^3 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^1 u^3 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^2 u^3 +p(\frac{u^1 u^0}{c^2}) & \mu u^3 u^3 +p(\frac{u^3 u^3}{c^2}-1) \end{matrix}\right )$$

which you can see gives a unnecessarily complicated expression and it should somehow reduce to the one shown at the beginning. I think I probably shouldn't write the explicit expression and consider symmetry properties or deduce beforehand the form of the Lorentz transformation, but really I have no idea on how to proceed on this one.

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: @G.Smith $\epsilon$ is the internal energy, and $h$ is the enthalpy.

Comment: Try setting $u^\mu=(c,0,0,0)$.

Comment: @G.Smith in this case I see that all non-diagonal elements must cancel, that is $u^\mu u^\nu=0$ for $\mu\neq\nu$. Also, the diagonal terms besides $T^{00}$ will contain null 4-velocity components, so with some algebra I can arrive at the result. However, if you don't mind me asking, is the physical meaning of setting $u^\mu=(0,0,0,0)$ correct? That is, that all the average velocities of particles in the inertial frame cancel each other?

Comment: You mean $u^\mu=(c,0,0,0)$. That four-velocity means that you’re now in the frame where the fluid isn’t moving; its 3-velocity is zero. That doesn’t mean that every molecule in the fluid isn’t moving. They’d be moving around, but with no macroscopically-averaged overall motion. You’re not dealing here with a microscopic description of fluid as a bunch of particles. You’re dealing with a macroscopic fluid-dynamics description.

Comment: The other task is to figure out a Lorentz transformation that turns an arbitrary four-velocity into an “at rest” four-velocity, and show that it transforms the tensor as expected.

Comment: @G.Smith yeah sorry, I meant to write $u^\mu=(c,0,0,0)$. I see, so it's the same physical notion since we're dealing with macroscopic quantities. Now, if I have a general 4-velocity given by $u^\mu=(c,u_x,u_y,u_z)$, then there should exist some Lorentz transformation $\Lambda^\mu_\nu$ such that $\Lambda^\mu_\nu u^\nu=(c,0,0,0)$, which can be solved using algebraic methods (althought I think it would be easier to write the explicity Lorentz transforms as 4 equations).